# Is there a way to operate each element from a list separately in order?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an array list like this:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, -1, -2, -4, -8, -16, -32, -64]
```

and I want to take each element one by one and operate them arithmetically with other numbers.
The algebraic version is:

*x^3+12x^2+48x+64*

Being "x" the number of the array in the `[i]` position

The output should be like:

```
[125, 216, 512, 1728, ..., -216000]
```

I tried with a for cycle counting the number of elements in the array (14 in this case) and using it as the range. But I still get the error "list index out of range".

```
for i in range(numElements):
            x = factors[i]
```

Please if you need more information tell me.

Comment: How are `numElements` and `factors` defined?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function to perform this operation. Then loop through your list, calling that function on each element like so:

```
def operate(num):
  return num**3+12*num**2+48*num+64

nums = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, -1, -2, -4, -8, -16, -32, -64]
output = [operate(num) for num in nums]
```

Comment: This is the cleanest and most reusable.

Answer (score 0):

```
k=[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, -1, -2, -4, -8, -16, -32, -64]    
result=[x**3+12*x**2+48*x+64 for x in k]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define a function, `operate` for convenience.

```py
def operate(x):
    return x ** 3 + 12 * x ** 2 + 48 * x + 64
```

### Option 0 - Using `for` loop

The simplest way to solve this is to use a for loop as you intended.

```py
def operate(x):
    return x ** 3 + 12 * x ** 2 + 48 * x + 64

nums = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, -1, -2, -4, -8, -16, -32, -64] # your input list

result = []
for num in nums:
    result.append(operate(num))
```

You might be getting the error, "list index out of range", if you are trying to access the index, `i`, which is out of the length of the list. Try using `len(nums)` instead of manually counting. You can write the for loop as,

```py
for i in range(len(nums)): 
    x = nums[i]
```

But its preferred to use the above method if you want to be more "pythonic".

### Option 1 - Using list comprehension

We can apply this function to each of the elements of the `nums` list. [List comprehension documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```py
def operate(x):
    return x ** 3 + 12 * x ** 2 + 48 * x + 64

nums = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, -1, -2, -4, -8, -16, -32, -64] # your input list
result = [operate(x) for x in nums]
```

### Option 2 - Using map

Another method is to use the `map` function, which takes in the *function* you want to apply on the *iterable* [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```py
def operate(x):
    return x ** 3 + 12 * x ** 2 + 48 * x + 64

nums = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, -1, -2, -4, -8, -16, -32, -64] # your input list
result = list(map(operate, nums))
```

### Operation 3 - Using lambda

If you are looking for a one-liner solution, you should consider [lambda functions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) with `map`.

```py
result = list(map(lambda x: x ** 3 + 12 * x ** 2 + 48 * x + 64, nums))
```

Comment: You just compiled, all the answers bellow :))